# How to update votes client side using WebForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm trying to implement voting very similar to Stack Overflow's. There are multiple items that all have a vote button next to it. Currently, I have it working, but it's done server side, posts back, and takes a while to reload the data. Here is the flow:

1. You click the vote button,
2. it fires a javascript function which clicks a hidden ASP.NET button (did it this way because there are multiple vote buttons per page),
3. the button fires,
4. it updates the database, and then
5. the page posts back and refreshes, showing the update.

How do I leverage javascript and AJAX to eliminate this bad user experience? I want it to work like Stack Overflow's, but I'm not using MVC. Any help, examples, suggestions would be great. Thanks.

**Update:**

I have this implemented, but when I place breakpoints on the Web Method it doesn't even fire and I always get the error alert. Any ideas?

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id^=VoteMeUp]").click(function (event) {
            var dta = '{ "VoteId":' + $(event.target).val() + '}';
            $.ajax(
                  {
                      type: 'POST',
                      data: dta,
                      url: 'Default.aspx/SaveUpVote',
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (data) {
                          //$(event.target).text("Vote Casted");
                          alert("Vote Casted");
                      },
                      error: function (x, y, z) {
                          alert("Oops. An error occured. Vote not casted! Please try again later.");
                      }
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Code Behind (you can use C#, I'm familiar with both):**

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function SaveUpVote(ByVal VoteID As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim test As Boolean = False
    Dim mySQL As New SQLHandler
    test = mySQL.UpdateVoteByID(VoteID)

    Return test
End Function
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="image" src="images/vote.png" id="VoteMeUp1" value="321" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a vote is cast for a given button, call the server method using ajax (for aspx) as follows:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=VoteMeUp]").click(function(event) {
      var dta = '{ "VoteId":' + $(event.target).val() + '}';
      $.ajax(
          {
            type: 'POST',
            data: dta,
            url: 'Default.aspx/SaveUpVote',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              $(event.target).text("Vote Casted");
            },
            error: function(x, y, z) {
              alert("Oops. An error occured. Vote not casted! Please try again later.");
            }
          }
        );
    });
  });
```

In Default.aspx.cs

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SaveUpVote(int VoteId)
    {
        string UpdateSQL = "UPDATE TableName SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE PKID = @VoteId";
        //do DB stuff
        return;
    }
```

Sample HTML:
...

```
<body>

    <button id="VoteMeUp1" value="817">1 - Vote for this</button>
    <button id="VoteMeUp2" value="818">2 - Vote for that</button>

</body>
```

...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This may be a dumb question, but, it's worth asking. I will have numerous buttons on the page, like below. How do I get the javascript function to know which one without having to write out the function on page load with an instance for each one?  `<body>  
  <button id="VoteMeUp1">Vote</button>  
  <input id="vid1" type="hidden" value="817"></input>  
  <button id="VoteMeUp2">Vote</button>  
  <input id="vid2" type="hidden" value="818"></input>  
  <button id="VoteMeUp3">Vote</button>  
  <input id="vid3" type="hidden" value="819"></input>  
</body>`

Comment: This is a very good question. You can set the "id" of the button (or whatever element type your app employs) to the name of the database table's column name. I have amended my answer to illustrate this technique.

Comment: Hey Ron,  you actually had it closer before. The column name will be the same each time, and you answered the first part of my question with your edit `$("[id^=VoteMeUp]")` - but the second part is for each VoteMeUp, there will be a vid, how do i put that into the dta? Essentially next to each vote button is the number of votes, so I want to update that field once the insert is complete, and just pop an alert if an error happens (user not logged in, etc)

Comment: ie: `<button id="VoteMeUp1"><span id="vid1">12 Votes</span><button id="VoteMeUp2"><span id="vid2">9 votes</span>` etc...

Comment: In that case we can just set the "value" property of the <button> to the VoteId and we don't need the hidden input. Check out the amended answer.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. I believe I'm pretty close. Something is going wrong, though. I keep getting the error alert. I added my code above to give you some insight as to what I'm doing. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The "z" argument will describe the error and will be helpful in understanding what is going wrong. is the name of the aspx file "Default"?

Comment: and the z argument is displaying nothing. when I do alert(z);

Comment: That is strange. At this point you will need to debug both client/server. Place "debugger" before "var dta" and use IE. After the debugger opens, place break-points within the "success" and "error" functions. You can also just set a break-point inside the VB function. Then use the immediate window to display variables (y,z), data if success.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest method to do this would be WebMethods.

Add a ScriptManager to your page with EnablePageMethods set to true

aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Assign a web method attribute to the method which increments the votes in your (c# here) code behind:

c# code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod] 
public string ChangeVote(string Arg){
    ...logic to change votes
}
```

in your javascript event, you can then access the code behind via pagemethods, and define functions to call on success and fail cases:

javascript:

```
PageMethods.ChangeVote("sent item", OnChangeVoteComplete,OnChangeVoteFail);

function OnChangeVoteComplete(arg){
    //arg is the returned data
}

function OnChangeVoteFail(arg){
    //do something if it failed
}
```

the success function receives the data returned by the WebMethod. You can use this to update the display on the page.

Comment: This all makes sense, thanks a lot. I'm having a little trouble understanding the javascript portion though. Where do I place the OnChangeVoteComplete and OnChangeVoteFail? Are these just other methods to add to my class? Also, in testing, I'm not getting the function to fire off my onclick event...

Comment: the OnChangeVoteComplete and OnChangeVoteFail are javascript functions that get called on the client side after the server side processing is complete. OnChangeVoteComplete one will receive any returned data from the WebMethod as a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When use clicks on the UpVote button, make an ajax call to the server where you execute a query againist the database to increment the vote.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="aUpVote">Vote UP </a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  $("#aUpVote").click(function(){

     $.post("myajaxserverpage.aspx?qid=12",function(data){
            alert(data);
     });     

  });

});

</script>
</head>
```

and in the server page (myajaxsever.aspx), read the values and execute your query to increment the Vote column value. value of qid is the question id this you can read from the page because it is going to be dynamic.